# Linq/Entity Framework syntax for adding a record to a database

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I need to add a record to a database using the Entity Framework. Since I'm brand new to using this syntax I am not sure how to properly write the code (Below is my best guess).

First, the agent must have their info inserted into the `Agent` table. This table produces a self-incrementing primary key known as a `SymNumber`. I then need to take that `SymNumber` and use it as a primary key for an insert into the `AgentIdentification` table.

I have run this code a couple of times, and I do not come up with an error, however since I am using a unit test to test the code I cannot tell for sure if the agent is being added properly. Secondly, I know for a  fact that I am not correctly grabbing the `SymNumber` as generated by the `Agent` table after the first insert. The `SymNumber` is an int value in the Linq code set to 0, and this does not change during the `AgentIdentification` insert.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
        AgentResourcesEntities _db = new AgentResourcesEntities();

        try
        {
            Agent agent = new Agent();
            agent.EntityType = "P";
            agent.FirstName = agentNewTraining.FirstName;
            agent.LastName = agentNewTraining.LastName;
            agent.LastChangeOperator = agentNewTraining.Requestor;
            agent.LastChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(agentNewTraining.NameSuffix)) agent.NameSuffix = agentNewTraining.NameSuffix;

            _db.Agent.AddObject(agent);

            AgentIdentification agentIdentification = new AgentIdentification();
            agentIdentification.SymNumber = agent.SymNumber;
            agentIdentification.ReferenceType = "S";
            agentIdentification.DummyReference = 0;
            agentIdentification.LastChangeOperator = agentNewTraining.Requestor;
            agentIdentification.LastChangeDate = DateTime.Now;

            _db.AgentIdentification.AddObject(agentIdentification);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: I understand, I am just trying to get the key pieces of this working right now. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to call

```
_db.SaveChanges();
```

to get your changed persisted.

But if you want also synchronize (get the new generated value) your `agent.SymNumber` you will need to call `SaveChanges()` right after adding it to context.

So the code will be like:

```
/// ...... ////
_db.Agent.AddObject(agent);
_db.SaveChanges();

AgentIdentification agentIdentification = new AgentIdentification();
agentIdentification.SymNumber = agent.SymNumber;  // sym number is now synchronized from DB
 ///...../////

_db.AgentIdentification.AddObject(agentIdentification);
_db.SaveChanges();
```

But if `SymNumber` is foreign key so the `AgentIdentification` has could have reference to some `Agent` instance, you can just tie those instances with that reference and would not need to call that additional `SaveChanges()` in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Call `_db.SaveChanges()` after inserting.